# Deploy angular (hottowel) app in apache httpd

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, apache

I've generated a project with john papas hottowel.

```
gulp serve-build
```

is working.

When I drop the build folder to my apache server the app is not working. It's not finding the files, although they are there.

```
localhost/:15 GET http://localhost/styles/lib-7947d5e2c5.css 
localhost/:17 GET http://localhost/styles/app-ba4747fbb6.css 
localhost/:34 GET http://localhost/js/lib-e827a87368.js 
localhost/:36 GET http://localhost/js/app-9e5293691e.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The index.html is found.

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/lib-7947d5e2c5.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-ba4747fbb6.css">
</head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="js/lib-e827a87368.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app-9e5293691e.js"></script>
    </body>
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to turn off HTML5 Mode and change base URL.

Turn off HTML5 mode in `app/blocks/router-helper.provider.js`.

`Line 18: $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`

Comment out base in `index.html`

`Line 17: <base href="/">`

By doing this your web app will route to a 404 by default. To fix this you can change the core route to `/` instead of `/404` within `app/core/core.route.js`

By doing this you will get a `#/` within your URL.